# How do I reduce the size of a Mac application bundle?

Tags: macos, size, bundle

I have a 120MB bundle that when is compressed (zip) is only 30MB.
I, however, so not want to distribute a zip file. I want to distribute a bundle in a dmg.

Are there any tools I can use that will enable me to compress my bundle, but also preserve the bundle file structure so that no 'unzip' tool is needed by end-users?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do want to distribute as a DMG? I find .zip files a lot more pleasant to use.

Comment: Just trying to follow a standard way of doing things.Why do you prefer zip files?

Comment: No "unzip" tool is needed by end-users on the Mac.  You just double-click the zip file, and Finder invokes the Archive Utility to open it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just discovered "hdiutil -format UDBZ" which creates a bzip2 compressed image.